# calculating days from dates in r

Tags: r

I have been trying to calculate the number of days between the patients visit using the `difftime` function and I have been getting this particular error code:

> restwan_data %>% select("PCode", "VisitDate") %>% na.omit() %>%
> group_by("PCode") %>% as.double(difftime(now, VisitDate, units = c("days")))
> Error in as.POSIXct.default(time1) :
> do not know how to convert 'time1' to class “POSIXct”

This is the code I used:

```
restwan_data %>% select("PCode", "VisitDate") %>% na.omit() %>%
group_by("PCode") %>% as.double(difftime(now, VisitDate, units = c("days")))
```

This is the data set:

`structure(list(PCode = c("57651", "57652", "57664", "57668",  "57671", "57671", "57688", "57689", "57692", "57695"), VisitDate = structure(c(1586304000,  1586304000, 1586908800, 1586390400, 1586304000, 1587168000, 1586908800,  1607040000, 1586476800, 1586649600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct",  "POSIXt")),` "PCode"`= c("PCode", "PCode", "PCode", "PCode",  "PCode", "PCode", "PCode", "PCode", "PCode", "PCode")), class = c("grouped_df",  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(`"PCode" `= "PCode", .rows = structure(list(1:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of",  "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))`

Any help to resolve this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that not all arguments to `difftime()` are yet of the proper Datetime format (i.e. class `POSIXct`).

One fix is to create a proper `now` object:

```
> now <- Sys.time()
> now
[1] "2021-11-02 07:37:46.487306 CDT"
> class(now)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
>
```

Then, with the `structure` output you kindly provided (good move!!) in `D`:

```
> D$dt <- as.numeric(difftime(now, D$VisitDate, "days"))
> D
   PCode  VisitDate PCode      dt
1  57651 2020-04-08 PCode 573.526
2  57652 2020-04-08 PCode 573.526
3  57664 2020-04-15 PCode 566.526
4  57668 2020-04-09 PCode 572.526
5  57671 2020-04-08 PCode 573.526
6  57671 2020-04-18 PCode 563.526
7  57688 2020-04-15 PCode 566.526
8  57689 2020-12-04 PCode 333.526
9  57692 2020-04-10 PCode 571.526
10 57695 2020-04-12 PCode 569.526
>
```

Of course, you can assign any other relevant anchor date to `now` as well.